# Tap em UIButton entre duas UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c

boa noite! Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma UIView (1) que contem: Uma UIView (2) e um UIButton (3).

O UIButton fica metade dentro da UIView(1) e metade na UIView(2) (porém na arvore, está dentro da UIView(1)) e a visualização é normal mas o tap na parte de cima do botão não funciona.

Alguém sabe resolver isso?

[image: Problema]

[image: Stack]

Comment: Cara, repliquei aqui a forma como vc fez e consegui clicar na parte de cima do botão. To tentando entender o que está acontecendo com vc.

Comment: Sim, acabei de ver isso também... Mas mesmo que eu coloque essa constraint relativa ao Top Layout Guide continua dando problema... Que tipo de constraint eu coloco então?

Comment: Já resolveu o problema?? O q não ficou claro para mim é se a UIView1 vai até embaixo da UIView2.